# Why do I get "cannot find symbol" compilation error using Generic class instance method?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I have this generic class:

```
final class Box<T> {
   public T t;

   public void add(T t) {
      this.t = t;
   }

   public T get() {
      return t;
   }
}
```

Given that there is another class `Group`, I am trying the following:

```
Box group1=new Box<Group>();
Group group = methodThatReturnsAGroupObject();
group1.add(group);
System.out.println(group1.get().getMembers().getValue());
```

Trying to compile this throws a "cannot find symbol" error for `getMembers()`.  If I replace `group1.get()` simply with `group`, it compiles without issue.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: So it was explained that my first line should have been:

```
Box<Group> group1=new Box<Group>();
```

But after updating to that, I am still getting the compiler error about "cannot find sybol".  So as it is no longer a raw type, what other mistake am I making?

Comment: At the end of "What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?" it says we should use Generics.  I thought I was using a generic.  How/Why is this a raw type issue and not a generic issue?

Comment: You used the generic type argument in the new instance creation expression but not in the variable type.

Comment: You need to say `Box<Group> group1 = new Box<Group>()`.  Otherwise the *variable* is still a raw type, the assigned value notwithstanding.

Comment: Your method invocations are done on the variable, which is of a raw type.

Comment: I updated my code to `Box<Group> group1=new Box<Group>();` and still get the same compiler error.

Comment: But perhaps I am also tackling my issue in the wrong way. I am trying to have the variable `group` be one of two class types (Group or Role) based on a conditional.